# How to include external javascript file without using the script tag

Tags: javascript

I am using a web app for my ecommerce store where they only allow you to add javascript via their input box.  You are suppose to add javascript without any script tags.

However, I am trying to integrate a 3rd party analytics tools using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="xxxx" async></script>
```

How can I add this to the input box without using script tags though? Are there alternative methods?

Thks

Comment: @Taplar — The CMS only allows JS to be added by entering the JS source code directly into a text box on a form.

Comment: you probably just add the source for your javascript. So just input the url to that library using a CDN and it will probably work fine

Comment: @LelioFaieta — It a 3rd party analytics tool, so it probably depends on cookies being set by the `Set-Cookie` header on the response to the request for the URL for the script (hosted on the analytic services servers). Copying it to a CDN would break that. It would also break updates to the script. It also wouldn't solve the problem because using a CDN just changes the URL and the OP's problem is that they can't add a `<script>` tag to type the URL into the src attribute of!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write JS to modify the DOM to insert the script element.

```
(function () {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "xxx";
  script.async = true;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
})();
```

Comment: Would this work for older browsers (IE < 9 etc.) that don't support document.head? Seems like the following would be a better approach: `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(sc);`

Comment: You could if you really wanted to support a beyond-end-of-life browser with a general market share as close to zero as makes no practical difference.